# Test execution using gradle connectedAndroidTest does not execute parallely on all connected devices

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am performing instrumented test execution using gradlew connectedAndroidTest on physical devices. But while doing this, I observe that irrespective of number of devices connected to my machine, at max 3-4 devices only have the tests running.

For Example - If I have 10 android devices connected to my machine, and I start execution of instrumented tests using gradlew connectedAndroidTest, it first starts the instrumented test on 3-4 devices. Then once any of the device is finished execution, it randomly picks up another device and starts execution.

Thus would like to understand that is there a way to control that on how many devices the instrumented test would be running?